# Find an array length without the use of the Array.Length method c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i would like to know how i would go about finding the length of an array without the use of the array.length method rather what does the array.length method acheive?

I had some homework to complete some arbituary array sorting without the use of the array.length method and i was curious as to how c# finds the array length does it go through the array counting each non null value and returns a value or is there a specific memory value associated to an arrays length that can be accessed more out of curiosity then anything else i was just wondering what goes on behind the scenes of the length method

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve; is this a homework-type question?

Comment: yes and no i had some homework to complete some arbituary array sorting without the use of the array.length method and i was curious as to how c# finds the array length does it go through the array counting each non null value and returns a value or is there a specific memory value associated to an arrays length that can be accessed more out of curiosity then anything else i was just wondering what goes on behind the scenes of the length method

Comment: It doesn't need to count; the length is stored with the array itself. And it doesn't matter whether the elements are null or not.

Comment: Im not after some basic for loop or foreach count code i would like to know the logic on how to get the length anyone can dump a foreach loop into a question but what values are stored in sysem with an array class item ???

Comment: It appears that `Array.Length` is implemented in the runtime, and is probably an implementation detail, see [Microsoft Code Reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/array.cs.html#mscorlib/system/array.cs) - you can see in the same file that `GetEnumerator` (which is used by foreach) ultimately relies on `Length` property and `GetLength` method. .NET has no other safe way of ascertaining the length of an array than `Length` and `GetLength` (see Thomas Levesque's answer)

Comment: thank you that was exactly what i was after cheers VisualMelon

Comment: I appreciate all the Constructive help guys about my misunderstanding of how array length values are stored

Comment: Why would you turn an O(1) operation (the array's `Length` property) into an O(n) operation?

Conceptually, an array is just a fixed-length,  contiguous chunk of memory: it's length is an intrinsic property of the array. Ditto for `List<T>`: the only difference is that `List<T>` uses an array as its backing store and reallocates a new one as needed (and then copies the old to the new.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be one way:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in YourArray)
{
   count++;
}
```

count will hold how many items there are in the array.

EDIT:
Ofcourse i forgot if you cant use the dreaded Length property the you can use the `Count()` method.

Comment: but the obvious question is why would you want to use this method.

Comment: @TMcKeown lol the obvious question would be why OP wants it.

Comment: but this is not the answer its just a way of getting around not using the array.length method ??? what i am asking is what does the array.length method do

Comment: "Find an array length without the use of the Array.Length method c#",in this title lies my answer :).

Comment: True i suppose how i constructed my question and the answer i was after were a little diffrent either way, to the question you have the corect answer however if someone does know can they tell me were to find it as i have searched the microsoft docs and tried pulling apart the c# method files to find out at a base level how it works

Comment: @Matthewkingston  probably,and i mean probably view it this way:when you initialize the array like int[] arr = new int[5];you are setting its length because you have yet to add items but if you call length it will return 5 already,so upon initialization the array defines the length.

Comment: yea but i was interested in an incomming array from another method at which i did not manually set the array length i can see now from Visual Melons post that the length of the array is stored as part of the array class perameters.

Answer (score 2):

A really awful way but to cover all grounds this **would** work but I stronger discourage this.

```
int[] test = new int[10];
int count = 0;
     try
      {
         for (; ; )
         {
          count++;
          test[count].ToString();
         }
      }
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
  {
  }
Console.Write(count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `theArray.GetLength(0)`, but it's basically the same as using `theArray.Length`, just more verbose...

Answer (score 0):

Getting length of the array without  using the `Array.Length` property is nearly impossible.

Well, you can:

1. Use enumerators(in `foreach` statement or through `LINQ`) and count the elements they give to you, but it will
   be just an indirection - `ArrayEnumerator` obviously uses
   `Array.Length` internally.
2. Use unsafe code and get the length, because it is stored before the
   actual data (4 or 8 bytes before the actual first element).
3. Probably you can even get some information from managed heap about
   the array reference and calculate the length, but if it is
   possible it will be a hack, and even if we somehow learn that memory
   allocated for the array is 100 byte, we can't be sure that all this memory is used

**PROPOSED SOLUTION:**

But what has probably been meant is the use of array terminators, like '\0' chars C runtime uses to terminate its strings.

To use array terminators you just arbitrary select some value(usually greatest or smallest) and use it as an array terminator:

```
Int32[] data = new Int32[] {10, -5, 100, Int32.MinValue};
PrintDataWithoutLength(data, Int32.MinValue);   


PrintDataWithoutLength<T>(T[] data, T terminator)
{
     for(Int32 i = 0; !data[i].Equals(terminator) ; i++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
     }
}
```